# Spring Cloud Kubernetes ConfigMap reload not working

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, minikube, configmap, spring-cloud-kubernetes

I was playing with Kubernetes in Minikube. I could able to deploy spring boot sample application into Kubernetes.

I am exploring Kubernetes configMap. I could successfully run a spring boot application with a spring cloud starter and picking the property keys from config map. Till here I am successful.

The issue I am facing currently is configmap reload.

Here is my config map :

**ConfigMap.yaml**

```
 apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: minikube-sample
  namespace: default
data:
  app.data.name: name
  application.yml: |-
    app:
      data:
        test: test
```

**bootstrap.yaml**

```
management:
    endpoint:
        health:
            enabled: true
        info:
            enabled: true
        restart:
            enabled: true
spring:
    application:
        name: minikube-sample
    cloud:
        kubernetes:
            config:
                enabled: true
                name: ${spring.application.name}
                namespace: default
            reload:
                enabled: true
```

**HomeController:**

```
package com.minikube.sample.rest.controller;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.minikube.sample.properties.PropertiesConfig;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Lookup;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

/**
 * @author Gorantla, Eresh
 * @created 06-12-2018
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeResource {

    @Autowired
    PropertiesConfig config;

    @GetMapping("/data")
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseData> getData() {
        ResponseData responseData = new ResponseData();
        responseData.setId(1);
        responseData.setName(config.getName());
        responseData.setPlace("Hyderabad");
        responseData.setValue(config.getTest());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(responseData, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public class ResponseData {
        private String name;
        private Integer id;
        private String place;
        private String value;
    }
}
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minikube-sample
  namespace: default
spec:
  selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: minikube-sample

  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: minikube-sample
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: minikube-sample
          image: minikube-sample:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Never
          ports:
            - containerPort: 8080
          env:
            - name: env.namespace
              value: default
          volumeMounts:
            - name: config
              mountPath: /config
      volumes:
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: minikube-sample
```

I used @ConfigurationProperties to reload properties.

**Dependencies**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

**What I did ?**
I have gone through spring cloud documentation.  **"The view role on the service account is required in order to listen for config map changes."**
Then I created cluster view role through below command

```
C:\Users\eresh.gorantla\apps\minikube-sample\src\main\fabric8 (master -> origin)
λ kubectl create clusterrolebinding minikube-sample --clusterrole=view --serviceaccount=default:minikube --namespace=default
clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/minikube-sample created
```

But when I update the configmap in kubernetes, the properties are not reloaded on the fly.
I suspect something wrong in clusterrolebinding. 
Please provide your thoughts. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you got any error? What K8s version are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Deployment doesn't have `serviceAccountName` configured so it uses the `default` service account. The command in the question, however - `kubectl create clusterrolebinding ... --serviceaccount=default:minikube...` - is for an account named `minikube` in the `default` namespace.

Moreover, creating `clusterrolebinding` may be "too much" when `rolebinding` for the namespace would work.

With the Deployment being for the `default` namespace (`metadata.namespace: default`), this should create a proper `rolebinding` to grant read-only permission to the `default` account:

```
kubectl create rolebinding default-sa-view \
  --clusterrole=view \
  --serviceaccount=default:default \
  --namespace=default
```

For reference, see [Using RBAC Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/).

Answer (score 2):

To access ConfigMaps and get Refresh events:

1. see annotations on config properties class
   `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)`
   see also `@RefreshScope` on config properties class.

   ```
   @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
   @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bean")
   @RefreshScope
   public class ClientConfig {

    private String message = "Default Message from java code - to be overwritten from config";

    public String getMessage() {...
    public void setMessage(String message) {...
   }
   ```

2 Add permissions to access ConfigMaps

```
kubectl create -f perm.yaml -n <NAMESPACE>
```

where perm.yaml is:

```
  kind: Role
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    namespace: yldbg
    name: namespace-reader
  rules:
    - apiGroups: ["", "extensions", "apps"]
      resources: ["configmaps", "pods", "services", "endpoints", "secrets"]
      verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  ---
  kind: RoleBinding
  apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
  metadata:
    name: namespace-reader-binding
    namespace: yldbg
  subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: default
    apiGroup: ""
  roleRef:
    kind: Role
    name: namespace-reader
    apiGroup: ""
```

- After creating permissions, deploy pods and services.
- when modifying the config map, you will see a refresh event in pod logs

  ```
  EventBasedConfigurationChangeDetector - Detected change in config maps
  EventBasedConfigurationChangeDetector - Reloading using strategy: REFRESH
  PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration - Located property source: [BootstrapPropertySource {name='bootstrapProperties-configmap.client-svc.myns'}]
  SpringApplication - The following profiles are active: kubernetes
  ```

by yl

Comment: For me setting the permission to access ConfigMaps (to the default namespace in my case), as explained in this answer, did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks gears for your answer. rolebinding is enough with role view in the namespace for the configmap to be available in container.

I solved the problem with updating dependencies. The Spring boot version with 2.1.8.Release and version of spring-cloud-kubernetes 1.1.0.Release didn't work out for me. I suspect to many dependencies added. I cleaned up pom file and that worked well.

Pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.minikube.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>kubernetes-configmap-reload</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>minikube-sample</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Cloud Kubernetes</description>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-config</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

You can find repository link here -- https://github.com/ereshzealous/kubernetes-configmap-reload

Thanks
Eresh